# If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ then $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Say $f$ is analytic at on $B(z_0,R)-\{z_0\}$. Then $f$ has a Laurent series expansion 
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha_k(z-z_0)^k$$
We say $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ if  $~\exists~~ m \geq 1$ such that $\alpha_m \neq 0$ and $\alpha_l=0~~\forall l <m$.

> Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $R>0$. Suppose that $f$ is analytic on $B(z_0,R)-\{z_0\}$ and has a pole of order $m \geq 1$ at $z_0$. Then I need to show $|f(z_0)|=\infty$.

I have done the following: Since $f$ has pole of order $m$
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-m}^{\infty}\alpha_k(z-z_0)^k$$
Hence $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-m}g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ and $g(z_0)=\alpha_{-m}$. Now can we take the limit $z \rightarrow z_0$ on $|f(z)|$ and say the limit goes to $\infty$? We know the limit is bounded for $g(z)$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{1}{|z-z_0|}=\infty$.

Comment: You forgot to mention that $g(z)\to g(0) \neq0$.

Comment: yes, that is true. But I wanted to ask since $|g(z)|$ is bounded and the $\frac{1}{|z-z_0|}$ goes to $\infty$, can we say $|f(z)|$ is infinity?

Comment: No. The product of two numbers, one going to infinity and the other going to $0$ need not even have a  limit; if it has a limit the limit can be any number.

Comment: But $\alpha_{-m} \neq 0$ as $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$. so one limit is non-zero finite and another goes to $\infty$. In that case their product goes to infinity. Thanks I understand the point.

Comment: By definition (see Ahlfors, p. 127) an isolated singularity $z_0$ with $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$ is a *pole* of $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy function $g$ is going to non zero number and denominator going to $\infty$ hence the product goes to $\infty$. does this approch true ? when one function is going to $\infty$? i know it is when both converges in $\mathbb C$.but not about $\infty$ . can u give me bit hint on this ,that how can we prove this when we have $\infty$ in limits

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we can show that if $z_0$ is a pole, then the Laurent series has a finite number of negative powers. Then it is a direct consequence that the limit is unbounded.

Let $z_0$ be a zero of order $l$ of a function $f(z)$. Let $g(z)=\frac1{f(z)}$, so that $z_0$ is a pole of order $l$ of g(z).

We have that $$g(z)=(z-z_0)^l h(z)$$ and $$h(z_0)\neq 0$$

Then, $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^l} \frac{1}{h(z)}$$ but $h(z)$ is analytic at $z=z_0$ so we have 
$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-l} \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n=-1}^\infty a_{n+l}(z-z_0)^n$$

so that $f(z)$ has finitely many negative powers.

Now, if we take the limit as $z\rightarrow z_0$ we see that $|f(z)|\rightarrow \infty$ since it has at least one term $\frac1{z-z_0}$.

Comment: I think the last sum should be starting on $n=-l$ instead of $n=-1$.